# Apache does not load the page if PHP has errors

Tags: apache-2.2, php, 500-error

OK, so I noticed that apache drops a HTTP ERROR 500 every time PHP has a fatal error. While it might be a nice function, I want it disabled for debugging purposes. How can I do that?

Comment: Uh, Apache's 500 status doesn't in any way prevent you from debugging.

Comment: I know, but I prefer not going into logs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want to set `display_errors=1` and maybe some more error logging settings in `php.ini`.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I needed. Didn't think of that. Thank you!